# Refresh listview in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

In my android application, I have one spinner box  and two edit text box for adding item.When I click on add button all the data will store in database and display in  below Item list (listview display in my first image) by refreshing listview.

My problem is, when I click on add button at a time only one list is display and listview heading is also gone.
May be this problem is raised due to refreshing of listview.
I searched on google and found notifyDataSetChanged() method is used for refreshing list view but I don't know how notifyDataSetChanged() method is used in fragment?

Does anybody know how to use this method in fragment?

I am new to fragment. In my app all the java code is developed using fragment activity, and xml file is simple layout.(LinearLayout/RelativeLayout)

You can see my screen here:

**1)First image show list heading.**

[image]

**2)Second image show List item.**

[image]

Comment: always remember to call **notifyDatasetChanged()** method after updating the dataSet items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setAdapter again to your listview after adding new data. it will show new data int listview.
if not get, post your code where you setAdapter to listview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add item in Arraylist/List which you passed in Adapter then after you can call below code..

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Its working perfect.Now i can see that listview is refreshing but still I have one issue when I add item in below list, its only display one record instead of all list. All record are store in database but listview display only one record.Also i can not see column header of that listview.